# gosu error: failed switching to "root": operation not permitted

Tags: gosu

When I use `gosu ...` it shows error info `failed switching to "root": operation not permitted`

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.10.2-alpine3.15
RUN apk update && apk add ca-certificates
# download gosu
# ....
ARG USER=ansibler
ARG GROUP=ansibler
ARG UID=1000
ARG GID=1000
RUN addgroup -g $GID $GROUP && adduser -u $UID -G $USER -D $USER && \
    echo 'ansibler ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL' >> /etc/sudoers
ENTRYPOINT [ "/tmp/entrypoint.sh" ]
CMD [ "/bin/bash" ]
USER $USER
```

in my `entrypoint.sh`, I wanna use command ->  `gosu root sed -i -e ....` ,
After `docker build -t`, when i use `docker run` it
that show the error as below ->
`error: failed switching to "root": operation not permitted`